# MediaStore managedQuery not returning the newest files

Tags: android

I am querying the MediaStore to get the videos based on a duration of (MAX 15 seconds).

The problem I am facing is when I record a video using the gallery. Then, if I go to my app, this video does not show up in this cursor. However, if I go to the gallery and open the video, it is returned the next time I query.

Here is my query:

```
private Cursor getVideos() {
        _.log("getVideos");
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION };

        return managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION + "<=?" + " AND "
                        + MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION + ">=?" + " AND "
                        + MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE + ">=?", new String[] {
                        "15000", "1000", "1000" }, null);
    }
```

---

**Possible solution** would be to force a refresh before querying. I tried this using the following code which utilizes a MediaScannerConnection:

```
_.log("new MediaScannerConnection");
msc = new MediaScannerConnection(mContext, new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        _.log("onScanCompleted:"+path);
        msc.disconnect();
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        _.log("onMediaScannerConnected:" + MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        msc.scanFile(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath(),
                null);
    }
});
_.log("connect");
msc.connect();
synchronized (lock) {
    try {
        _.log("waiting");
        lock.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    _.log("done waiting");
}
```

However this did not solve the problem. On some phones, I am getting onMediaScannerConnected called multiple times and never onScanCompleted

Comment: Looks like old issue but still unanswered.. I also have the same issue . How did you solve the issue. Could you please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to unplug the phone you are testing this on. Do not plug it to the computer using a usb. Try to redo the whole thing. Tell me if the same is observed.

Comment: yes i tried it too. I then deleted all images and took new pictures opened the app again but my app shows wrong thumbnails, the thumbnails of the deleted images. I rooted my phone and checked the media database. thumbnail table didn't have any entry on LG P500, however on Galaxy SII i could see the thumbnail entries in database.

Comment: couldn't find the right solution then I tried to create my own thumbnail database within the app. a little resource consuming, but works for my needs.